# I create a telegram bot;but dont work

Tags: python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

I create a telegram bot whit python-telegram-bot. I have defined a list of words for the bot,and I want to manage the chat bot in the group, that is, if there is a word in the chats in the list defined, the bot will delete it. 
I added the bot to a group and admin it there, and the bot should control the messages sent to the group, and if there is a word in the message that is on the mlist, the bot should delete the message.
my codes:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
mlist=['world', 'by', 'hello']

def delete_method(bot, update):
    bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat_id, message_id=message.message_id, *args, **kwargs)

if message in mlist:
    delete_method(bot, update)

updater.start_polling()

# for exit
# updater.idle()
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The bot not deleting the messages?

Comment: "please tell me what is the problem" Why don't *you* tell us what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please narrow down your question to a specific call that's giving you a problem. Your question, as it currently is will probably not receive a good answer, and may be closed. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Comment: The robot is added to the group and it should be removed when the words in the mlist are posted in the group and by users;But the bot does not do it in the admin group!

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't registered any handler so nothing is handled.

You need to register handlers and the updates will be handled by that one when it is true.

Check [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) introduction. It is very clear.

EDIT: i write you an example of how your code should be (i didn't tested it, i wrote from my phone)

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler
import re

def delete_method(bot, update):
    if not update.message.text:
        print("it does not contain text")
        return

    mlist=['world', 'by', 'hello']

    for i in mlist:
        if re.search(i, update.message.text):
            bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, delete_method))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I know;I need to type in the second line of the token. I did it before, but did not work

Comment: please explain more

Comment: What should I add to the codes if the words in the mlist are in Persian or in a language other than Latin?

Comment: ;What should I add to the codes if the words in the list are in Persian or in a language other than Latin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612255/i-built-a-telegram-robot-but-it-does-not-workwhy

Comment: in a private chat with the bot, i cannot delete the message